# No output to monitor

Tags: display, vga

I have an old computer (early vista days) which i recently resurrected by placing a hard drive and ram into it. Upon booting, the fans made a lot of noise, but nothing showed on the screen (not even BIOS).

A few weeks later I attempted to boot it again without changing anything and it booted just fine. Today suddenly the monitor won't show any output again. What's going on and how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked that the monitor is reliable and tried a different monitor cable/inspected the connector pins for damage?

Comment: It would be unusual, but it is possible that a dead CMOS battery is preventing the PC from operating correctly. Ten years would be a good lifetime for a CR2032 cell.

Comment: I didn't, but if you would look at comments below you would see that the lights are not going on by the keyboard and mouse, suggesting it is more than monitor/cable issue.

Comment: In that case I would very much suspect the CMOS battery is dead. They are only about $2 each at most. If it doesn't end up being that, they have a shelf life of at least ten years (check the packaging for a date before buying) so you can save it to use in something else.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I replaced the battery... no joy. Probably the motherboard died.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with a Shuttle bare bones kit that had been working for months then simply died.  All the symptoms you describe sound just like mine.  Turns out the mother board had died.  Luckily mine was still under warranty.  Sounds like yours is not.

If your motherboard has a speaker, you can listen for POST beeps (power on self test) and use them to look up error codes.  Some motherboards have status LED lights or even numbers that tell you what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Start by Checking the ram is firmly inserted "remove and reinsert it, insure the "lock" is firmly locking it" and , if you have installed more than one stick try with only one.

if you have a laser/optical mouse connect it ,turn on the PC and wait a while then  check if the mouse or keyboard "Caps , Num or Screen" are responsive.

if the ram thing didn't work check if all the important connections are securely connected "don't forget the GPU".

try another PSU then another GPU if possible.

by the way was the noise way out of the ordinary ?